# How to select a point K with a known probability distribution?

Tags: matlab, probability

point K must be selected out of possible points, K is a random variable with known probability distribution. I want to choose one of the points due to this distribution... how can I do that?

For example:
the points:   3   5   6   8
probability: 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.3

I want to select one of the points due to their probabilities.

Comment: Believe me: you need this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8891-randp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll not provide you with an exact function, however, with the code provided below it should be extremely easy to wrap it into a function.

The solution is based on Marks original comment, but uses `cumsum()` to make the implementation a bit easier.

```
%# Set up point labels and probabilities (input parameters to function)
labels = [3 5 6 8];
probabilities = [0.2 0.4 0.1 0.3];

%#Find cumulative distribution
cp = [0 cumsum(probabilities)];

%#Draw point at random according to probability density
draw = rand();
higher = find(cp >= draw==1,1);
drawnPoint = labels(higher-1); %# Output result from function
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `rand` generate a random number in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`.  If it is in `[0.0,0.2)` select `3`, if the random number is in `[0.2,0.6)` select `5`, *etc, etc*.

Comment: Thanks. but what if when the points are too much... is there any way to define a function?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way to define a function.  If you have no experience of writing Matlab functions, writing this one would be a good introduction for you.  I'll provide more help when you post your code, but I won't write it for you.  I suppose someone else might come along and do that.

Comment: Thanks so so much. I have some experience, but not working with probability distributions. just tell me how to do it generally, I will write the code on my owwn...